# Bitmap made from Camera2 bytes huge

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am using Google's example given [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic). I have changed the `OnImageAvailableListener` in the following manner:

```
private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener
        = reader -> {
            Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
            ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
            buffer.get(bytes);
            image.close();

            String pictureId = "asdasd";

            Bitmap bitmap = createMutableBitmap(bytes);
            StorageClass.getInstance().put(pictureId, bitmap);


            Intent intent = new Intent(Camera2MainActivity.this, TPCameraPreviewSnapActivity.class);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.putExtra("pictureId", pictureId);

            startActivityForResult(intent, 1123);
        };
```

Where the new Intent I am starting is using [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) to show a Bitmap. The `StorageClass` provides a static way to share large data (such as these bitmaps) between intents.

Also, the method `createMutableBitmap` is:

```
public static Bitmap createMutableBitmap(byte[] data){
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inMutable = true;
    Log.d(TAG, "BT1: " + data.length);
    Bitmap mutableBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);
    Log.d(TAG, "BT2: " + mutableBitmap.getByteCount());
    return mutableBitmap;
}
```

Upon executing this code on a Huawei P30 Pro I get output like this:

```
W/ImageReader_JNI: Unable to acquire a buffer item, very likely client tried to acquire more than maxImages buffers
E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
D/Camera2BasicFragment: BT1: 1019119
W/ServiceManagement: getService: unable to call into hwbinder service for vendor.huawei.hardware.jpegdec@1.0::IJpegDecode/default.
D/HwAppInnerBoostImpl: asyncReportData rs.tp.camera2verifiedbypi,1,1,10,0 interval=2774
D/Camera2BasicFragment: BT2: 159694848
```

No matter how I change the JPEG quality of the image, the number `159694848` pops up. 159694848 bytes is ~160MB.

Afterward, when trying to set the `Bitmap` as the source for the

```
`PhotoView`, I get an exception:
E/BitmapDrawable: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap
W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(159694848bytes) bitmap.
```

This example, with my changes, works fine on all the other phones I've tried but they are running Android 8 or lower.

So, what is the cause of this issue and how can I alleviate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the resolution of the JPEG you're capturing?  A 160 MB Bitmap, assuming ARGB internal storage, is 4 bytes per pixel, so 160 /4 = 40 million pixels.

From https://www.gsmarena.com/huawei_p30_pro-9635.php, The Huawei P30 Pro does indeed have a 40 MP main camera (when used in the quad-bayer mode), so this is all consistent.

That said, Android View components aren't really expecting to be passed 40 megapixels worth of Bitmap; since the screen resolution is only 1080 x 2340 pixels = 2.5 MP, there's zero reason to try to draw 40 MP on that screen.

If you just want to display the JPEG on screen, you should use the BitmapFactory options to rescale the image to something closer to screen resolution when decoding it.  That'll save you huge amounts of memory as well.

Comment: Since this is my first attempt at working with Camera2 API, I am using the example Google provided with the changes stated above. I have not meddled with any further settings.

Comment: The default code picks the maximum listed output resolution, which appears to be 40 MP on this phone.   So I'd recommend using BitmapFactory.Options to downscale the Bitmap during decode. For example, with https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize ; I'd pick a power of two that gives you a roughly 2 MP output Bitmap, for display.

Answer (score 0):

A bitmap is always uncrompessed, it has nothing to do with the JPEG compression. A bitmap, in ARGB format, will always be the number of pixels x 4 for its size (1 byte each for alpha, red, green, blue). So if you have a 1000x1000 pixel bitmap, it will always be 4MB in size when loaded in memory. JPEG compression only applies to files stored to disk, in memory images are always uncompressed.

You can use smaller bitmaps by using 4 bits per channel, at the expense of color fidelity, or you can resize them.